# Adding certificate for a custom (private) Maven repository in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, ssl, intellij-idea, repository

I recently set up an Artifactory repository and secured it with an SSL certificate. It's not self-signed but while most operating systems come with it pre-installed, the JRE doesn't.

The problem is that the record containing my server in the Maven Repositories Preferences window (IntelliJ Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories) gives an error when pressing the Update button. Here's the abstract from `idea.log`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 57 more
```

So I tried adding our root certificate to IntelliJ's Server Certificates (IntelliJ Preferences > Tools > Server Certificates) and restarted IntelliJ, but the error remains.

Has any one else had any problems with this before?

Screenshot of my Preferences window:

[image: Maven Repositories Preferences]

Comment: Try adding the certificate into the JDK that is configured to run Maven in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Yes, good idea. But won't I have to redo that every time I update my JDK?

Comment: Yes, you will have to, until the CA you certificate is using is added into default JDK keystore.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work (or I did something wrong). I've imported the certificate into the keystore of both my own JDK install and the one that comes bundled with IntelliJ, but the error is still the same

Comment: My bad: it didn't work at first, but after invalidating and restarting (File > Invalidate Caches / Restart), I now get another error. So the certificate problem seems fixed!

Comment: @CrazyCoder Why doesn't it work by adding it to Server Certificates? Isn't that the function of this function? If not, what is it for?

Comment: @Mr.Mars it doesn't work because Maven starts in a different JVM while the certificate settings in IntelliJ IDEA are only for the JVM that is used to start the IDE itself. There are open requests to make it better: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124209
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173599 .

Comment: @CrazyCoder that setting is for IDEA itself, when it checks plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom truststore, import your certificate to it and make your JVM use it.

Create your truststore :

```bash
keytool -genkey -alias "yourtruststore" -keyalg "RSA" -keystore "/path/to/your/truststore.jks"
```

Import your certificate :

```bash
keytool -import -alias "your-certificate" -file "your-certificate.cer" -keystore "/path/to/your/truststore.jks" -storepass "changeit"
```

Make your JVM use it, via VM options :

```bash
"-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/your/truststore.jks" \
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

In IntelliJ IDEA : File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner :

[image: Maven settings]